# Blue underscore showing up in img tag HTML5

Tags: html, css, image

I am writing HTML5 specifically for **emails.** As such, I have to do all my CSS styling inline. I have a table with three images (all hosted on google drive) but this strange blue underscore is showing up?

Pictured:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWdsi.jpg

Relevant HTML:

```
    <table align="center"  style="max-width: 400px">
        <tr align="center">
            <td>
                <a href='https://www.twitter.com'>
                    <img src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1txAOBZTXT_J8RcM7fDaKXT-oO8hWV1fb" width="40" height="40"/>
                </a>


                <a href='https://www.facebook.com'>
                    <img  style="margin:0px 10px" src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1nFoCmmlS1Kl3nKXkJk9eDaRqglpTeVP1" width="40" height="40"/>
                </a>


                <a href='https://www.instagram.com'>
                    <img src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1LcrU78sAidvlnnzL28TgdaIYBY9xcN7q" width="40" height="40"/>
                </a>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: text-decoration:none of links

Answer (score 0):

Looks like these are the default underlines of the anchor tags (`<a>`) so adding `style="text-decoration: none"` on them should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the underscore is a space Character within your link. Try to remove all spaces between your tags within the link-tag. And remove all linebreaks in your source document within the links too.

Answer (score 0):

To remove this blue underline, add `text-decoration: none;` to the style of the `<a>` element.
Here is your code:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<table align="center"  style="max-width: 400px">
        <tr align="center">
            <td>
                <a href='https://www.twitter.com'>
                    <img src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1txAOBZTXT_J8RcM7fDaKXT-oO8hWV1fb" width="40" height="40"/>
                </a>


                <a href='https://www.facebook.com'>
                    <img  style="margin:0px 10px" src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1nFoCmmlS1Kl3nKXkJk9eDaRqglpTeVP1" width="40" height="40"/>
                </a>


                <a href='https://www.instagram.com'>
                    <img src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1LcrU78sAidvlnnzL28TgdaIYBY9xcN7q" width="40" height="40"/>
                </a>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

A living demo: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/PoPjgZE?editors=1100